# Use redis to maintain a cycled number sequence

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to generate different port numbers to use in different processes, so I'm considering using redis to maintain a cycled number list, like this:

```
function getNextPort(callback) {
  var DEFAULT_PORT = 10245;
  client.incr('next_port_incr', function(err, value) {
    if (value > 200) {
      client.del('next_port_incr');
    }
    var port = DEFAULT_PORT + value;
    callback(port);
  });
});
```

this way, each time I call `getNextPort` I can get a new port: 10246, 10247, 10248, ... and returns to 10246 after 200 times so the port wont get too large.

the problem is, since this function will be called by many processes at the same time, do I need to make it more *atomic* ? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "The counter pattern is the most obvious thing you can do with Redis atomic increment operations." in [redis increment docs](http://redis.io/commands/INCR) So I would say that you are just fine

Comment: I'm worried about `incr` and `del` are not in an atomic operation

Comment: True, but unless you have a zillion processes what will happen is that you might get some more processes using the 10246 port, because several processes issued a delete, so you are always restarting your counter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a race condition between `.incr` and `.del`. If multiple processes call `.incr` at the same time when current value is above `200` then you will endup with multiple ports above `DEFAULT_PORT + 200`. Is that an issue? Maybe. Depends on what exactly you are doing. I guess you are fine.